# Split XML file based on number of nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to split an XML file into groups. Limiting each to a given number of a certain node.

Sample input data:

```
    <RESULT>
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item1</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem1</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item2</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem1</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item3</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem3</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item4</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem4</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item5</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem5</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item6</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem6</DATA1>     
        </ROW> 
   </RESULT>
```

I've been able to get the below XSLT working to split the file into groups of 3 when there is data present only at the ROW node (for example: `<ROW>Item1</ROW>`).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
   <xsl:param name="group-size" select="3"/>
   <xsl:template match="/RESULT">
   <ROOT>
      <xsl:if test="count(//ROW) > 0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW"/>
      </xsl:if>
   </ROOT>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ROW">
      <xsl:if test="position() mod $group-size = 1">
        <RESULT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::ROW[position() &lt; $group-size]" mode="list"/>
        </RESULT>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ROW" mode="list">
      <ROW><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></ROW>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I'm not sure how this code needs to be modified to account for the additional data nodes and still split into groups of three rows, providing the desired outcome below. I greatly appreciate any and all help!

So the desired outcome should look like this:

```
    <RESULT>
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item1</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem1</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item2</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem1</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item3</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem3</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
    </RESULT>
    <RESULT>
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item4</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem4</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item5</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem5</DATA1>     
        </ROW>  
        <ROW>
            <DATA>Item6</DATA>      
            <DATA1>SubItem6</DATA1>     
        </ROW> 
   </RESULT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[position() mod $group-size = 1]"/>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="group-size" select="3"/>

    <xsl:template match="/RESULT">
        <ROOT>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ROW[position() mod $group-size = 1]"/>
        </ROOT>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <RESULT>
            <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::ROW[position() &lt; $group-size]"/>
        </RESULT>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```